# Where do I find a (recent) historical list of personnel strikes at European airports?

Tags: air-travel, europe, airports, disputes, industrial-action

Is there a publicly available register of industrial actions at European airports?

I actually need recent historical data to claim compensation for a cancelled flight. I want to verify the airline's explanation that the cancellation was due to strike and thus does not qualify under EU rules for compensation.

Comment: In what place was the (alleged) strike? It seems you are asking for a comprehensive list where a single newspaper report about a specific occurrance might suffice.

Comment: London City Airport, 9 April 2016. I did not ask for a specific piece of information because I was afraid of breaking some Stack Exchange rule which prohibits questions of limited interests, or whatever. You never know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a comprehensive list of airport strikes, because:

- There isn't a centralized union for airport employees in Europe
- Different parts of the airport can go on strike: baggage handlers, security, pilots, traffic controllers, taxi drivers, cleaning personnel, etc
- The level of disruption is highly variable: not every strike causes a full shutdown
- There are frequent *threats* to go on strike, but these threats are not always carried out for one reason or another

Therefore your best bet is to search Google News for strikes [at a specific airport](https://www.google.cz/search?espv=2&biw=1856&bih=1019&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A4%2F1%2F2016%2Ccd_max%3A4%2F30%2F2016&tbm=nws&q=%22london+city+airport%22+strike&oq=%22london+city+airport%22+strike&gs_l=serp.3...9594.15639.0.16597.35.35.0.0.0.0.170.2823.24j9.33.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..2.15.1315...0j30i10.KbakDmuyVEA), or try the [airport's](http://www.londoncityairport.com/) official website.